# Fast approximate evaluation of Fourier-Legendre series

Tags: fourier-analysis, approximation

Suppose I know that a function from $[0,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ may be written as

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_l \frac{2l+1}{4\pi} P_l(r)
$$

where $A_l$ all are known. Is there a way in which I may very quickly approximate the value of the function? My naive implementation is very slow and also suffers problems with numerical issues stemming from adding the very small numbers for certain $l$ and $r$ to large numbers.

A package or something in whatever language, Python, Julia, Fortran, etc, anything goes really, would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the original function? Also, did you try computing the summation in reverse order?

Comment: nope, that's the point is that I only know the coefficients $A_l$, and yes, but the evaluation kind of breaks for large L

Comment: Does the problem for large $l$ arises from $A_l$ or $P_l$?

Comment: oh, sorry for being unclear. In my naive attempts, P_l becomes impossible to evaluate for large l, even without $A_l$. Moreover, it is very, very slow. I am going to have to evaluate it in several points on the interval $[0,\pi]$, and I have to include a lot of terms, so it will be less than efficient...

Comment: I think that those details might be important enough to be included in the question. Maybe what you need is a fast and reliable way of evaluating $P_l$ for large $l$.

Comment: @eja: You need to be a bit more clear. The summation should be over $l$ and not over $k$. We need access to $A_l$ to understand the decay of $A_l$. I am also assuming that $P_l(r)$ is the Legendre polynomial and $\vert r \vert \leq 1$.

Comment: There is no information of A_l, I pick it myself. You can use anything which decays.

Comment: I believe the correct way to do this is using Reinch's modification to the Clenshaw recurrence.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1093/imamat/20.3.379